# Files Manager Missing Window Frame/Global Menu

Tags: unity, globalmenu

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04. Suddenly Files manager is missing Window Frame/Global Menu. I have checked other Application such as Gedit, Firefox aren't having this problem. I've tried resetting unity by using these commands:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz
unity --reset-icons
```

But the problem still persists.

Screenshot of the problem:
[image: Screenshot]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have installed any package recently before the global menu went missing. Sometimes, installing `ubuntu-restricted-package` causes the issue, so you may try to remove it and install it again.

Answer (score 0):

Remove nautilus from compiz config's window decorator plugin exceptions.